# Where to obtain orders for First Prepper deliveries?

Tags: death-stranding

I just found the First Prepper and unlocked him by delivering the lost cargo order from the nearby Mule camp. Since then, I've been trying to locate additional orders from other settlements to help unlock the chiral network in his area, and have been unable to find any. I attempted delivering some standard orders for him, with the hope that those delivery locations would generate an order for delivery back to him, but so far only the Weather Station has done that.

Are there certain settlements that generate orders for the First Prepper, or is it random?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard orders are not random and here is the list with all of them: https://www.ign.com/wikis/death-stranding/List_of_Standard_Orders. I've extracted all orders to First Prepper:

- **Craftsman**: #209,  Antique Housewares Delivery (Fragile),  43 likes;
- **Timefall Farmer**: #226,    Old-fashioned Fresh Bread Delivery (Time-sensitive)     173;
- **Doctor**: #326, Old-fashioned Synthetic Liquor Delivery,    135;
- **First Prepper himself**: #396,  Old Gun Components Lost During Delivery,        51;
- **First Prepper himself**: #397,  Anti-chiralium Medication Collection,   168;
- **Weather Station**: #489,    Latest Meteorological Data Delivery, 17.

Additionally [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DeathStranding/comments/dxoezf/orders_for_veteran_porter_and_first_prepper/) lists two more orders:

> - Waystation North of Mountain Knot City: Resins & Alloys ~175 Likes
> - Waystation North of Mountain Knot City: Old US Army Ratings ~257 Likes

I also had troubles with First Prepper and other preppers deliveries, some hints:

- If your progress with them (or with any facility actually) is stuck you need to read all of their emails. If it doesn't help - rest in your private room and missing emails should appear.
- Always grab lost cargo addressed to them.